# null object reference when calling Fragment method

Tags: java, android

I am getting this error:

```
    Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.standa.vecerkaFirestore.MapFragment.testMethod()' 
on a null object reference
```

When i call the method within the fragment everything works fine, but when i call the method from another activity it throws me null pointer.

Why is this happening?

Code of activity from which I'm calling the method

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.botton_sheet_layout, container, false);
    final MapFragment frg = (MapFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    final Switch switch_open = v.findViewById(R.id.switch_open);

    switch_open.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (switch_open.isChecked()){
                frg.testMethod();

            }else{

            }
        }
    });
```

And here is code of the map Fragment :

```
   public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    public void testMethod(){
        double longitude = 14.450388;//location.getLongitude();
        double latitude =50.085913;// location.getLatitude();
        LatLng testerloc=new LatLng(latitude,longitude);

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(testerloc).title("yesCardOpen").snippet(""));


    }
}
}
```

I included only the test method.

Comment: How are you attaching the Fragment? Also, that `onCreateView()` method isn't from an Activity.

Answer (score 0):

[getFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#getFragmentManager()) gets the fragmentManager for the current activity. That is why it returns null.

What you should probably do is create a `Listener` to communicate from the second activity to the map fragment.